# How can i filter my onetoMany relationship select boxes in symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have OnetoMany Association with

`Product` will have many `vouchers`
But one voucher will be only linked to one product.

Now when i have the Product form then i have the Select Box where i can select multiple vouchers. But the problem is

If the voucher is previously linked to another product then it gets updated.

So is there any way /query so that in my select box i can see

1. All the vouhers which are not currently linked to any product (this ca be done)
2. Now But i also want to show the vocuhers which were previously linked to that current edited product

This is my code

```
 ->add('vouchers', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeMyBundle:Voucher',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.product_id = :id')
                                ->setParameter('id', 'NULL')
                    ->orderBy('u.name', 'DESC');
                        },
                'expanded'=> false,
                'multiple' => true
                    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your query. We don't know what your association looks like but assuming you are using `vouchers`.

```
//...
->where('u.product_id = :id')
->leftJoin('u.vouchers','v')
->having('COUNT(v.id) = 0')
->groupBy('u.product_id');
```